# Read Only in Datasheet view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, datasheet, multiline-text-field

I have a List that has a column that I changed from `single line` of text to `multi-line text` and now when in datasheet mode it tells me and my users the cell is **read-only**. it works fine in Standard View.

I tried deleting and re-adding the column but same results. I cannot find anything on how to fix this!!

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, it's by design, you can't edit the **multi-line text** with `Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)` type in datasheet view

**To overcome this issue**

**Specify the type of text to allow:** `Plain Text` or `Rich text (Bold, italics, text alignment, hyperlinks)` **instead of** `Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)`

[image]