# Why Can't I edit a Required Column in Grid View on SharepPoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, read-only, quick-edit, list-column

I am developing a company's SharePoint online site for internal communications. I have Full Control permissions to the entire site. I created a list called HR FAQs and want to grant editing permissions to only users with Full Control, plus an "HR Managers" group that has Edit permissions.

When setting up the list, I changed the label of the "Title" column to "Question," and added a required column called "Answer" of the Type *Multiple Lines of Text*, with the lines expanded to 9. In addition to being a member of the HR Managers group (temporarily, for development purposes), I have granted myself Full Control permissions to the list (in addition to already having Full Control of the entire site).

The problem comes when I try to add some dummy items to test and demonstrate the list to the HR team. I click "Edit in Grid View" and can enter a question, but then the Answer column is labelled as "read only," and I cannot update it. If I try to add questions one by one, using the standard form, I am able to add both Question and Answer.

Does anyone know why I can't edit all columns in this list in Grid View or Quick Edit mode? Is there any workaround?

[image: Image of: FAQ List in Grid View Showing Read-Only Column]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, I have the same result with you when we select the multi-line column type as Rich text:

[image]

And per my research I found this is by design,we can't edit the multi-line text with rich text (Bold, italics, text alignment, hyperlinks) type in datasheet view.

[image]

As a workaround, change the type to Plain text or Enhanced rich text(Rich text with pictures,tables,and hyperlinks)

Similar issues for your reference:

[Read Only in Datasheet view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219200/read-only-in-datasheet-view)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/45fd8464-9daf-47b7-9e35-326f3b771882/quotrich-textquot-field-will-be-disabled-inside-the-quick-edit-grid-while-quotenhanced-rich?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Enhanced Rich Text seems to work. Thank you!